# Make the box of the Description bigger

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-wall

I have made an FB App, to post in friends wall with php sdk

```
$facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', array())
```

but my "Description" is a little bigger than the box, so can anybody say me how I can make that box bigger?

[Image link](http://screencast.com/t/iAdV8YuuFv)

[image: http://screencast.com/t/iAdV8YuuFv]

Answer (score 1):

> but my "Description" is a little bigger than the box, so can anybody say me how I can make that box bigger?

You can’t, because Facebook sets the height of the box client-side via CSS. Everything that is bigger than the box height allows, might get loaded, but is displayed cut off via `overflow`.

And no, you can not manipulate Facebook’s stylesheets in this place.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the documentation related to the facebook app you are working on.

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/paSqaUXRpf

Here there are another example I wan't to make that box bigger, I found info about it but there are not at dev.fb